# How to get the entire line printed with Same Index name

Tags: python, list

How to print an index with a same name with a newline delimitted by priting the Index Name as a header:

i have below list values, where i have `Art`, `Science`  and `Geology` having multiple lines i want all the lines get printed with a same index value with a newline separator.

```
file = open('student.txt')
for line in file:
    fields = line.strip().split()
    print(fields)
```

Below is processed as above

```
['Jullu', '18', 'Art']
['sean', '25', 'Art']
['Rubeena', '18', 'Science']
['Kareen', '18', 'Science']
['Rene', '18', 'Geology']
['Babu', '18', 'Geology']
['Riggu', '18', 'Robotics']
```

the output i would like:

```
Art
    Jullu 18 Art
    sean 25 Art

Science
    Rubeena 18 Science
    Kareen 18 Science
```

More Exaplabation: The List output i have drawn above are the result processed from Bleow text file called, so we need to

```
$ cat student.text
Jullu d18 Art
seand d25 Art
Rubeenad d18 Science
Kareend d18 Science
Rened d18 Geology
Babud d18 Geology
Riggud d18 Robotics
```

My aopologies for not making it so claer at the first level.

Comment: what did you try? and may be it should be `Art` -> `Jullu` in the first line?

Comment: @BearBrown, i'm trying to split it into list  and trying to do but somehow as a newbie i'm stucking .. yes my bad  it should be Art -> Jullu
Just being a Medical Student , i getting it slowly but my bad logic in this area which i'm trying to learn.

Comment: Definitely a job for `itertools.groubpy`

Comment: @taras, thnx i'll try to understand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code in this way:

```
file = open('student.txt')
l=[]
for line in file:
    fields = line.strip().split()
    print(fields)
    l.append(fields)
```

Now `l` is a list of list, and you can do so:

```
sub = []
for i in l:
    sub.append(i[2])
sub = list(set(sub))
for i in sub:
    print i
    for index, j in enumerate(l):
        if i in l[index][2]:
            print '\t' + ' '.join(j)
```

Output:

```
Science
     Rubeena 18 Science
     Kareen 18 Science
Robotics
     Riggu 18 Robotics
Art
     Jullu 18 Art
     sean 25 Art
Geology
    Rene 18 Geology
    Babu 18 Geology
```

Comment: Guys, i need to process the data from the List not from the list of lists.

Comment: Just append them in a list before: `l = []` outside the for loop, and inside(after the print): `l.append(fields)` and procede with mine or others' code :)

Comment: Joe, many thanks for the revert , let me try the suggestion. Do we really need to have a list of list,  i have edited my post with more details in case you have any more additions.

Comment: @rocky1981 Ive updated the code, check it. Yes because you have to know in advance the data, not in real time

Comment: Correct Joe, thnx a mile again.

Comment: @rocky1981 You are welcome :) consider to upvote and accept the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Joe, as suggested code not working correctlty its giving some unwanted results i have updated my POST with results.. see if i m using wrong

Comment: The indentation you are using is wrong. 'for i in l:' has to be in the beginning of line, not inside the other for loop. Same 'for i in sub' at the beginning of line, not inside the other for loop

Comment: Same results Joe.

Comment: In python even a space is a different indentation. Have you carefully copied my code with che indentation i used? The code that you used in the edit of the answer is not ad the same ad mine. Indentation is the space between the beginning of line and beginning of characters

Comment: Thanks Joe, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to aggregate your lists by
the Index Name

```
import itertools
import operator

lst = [

['Jullu', '18', 'Art'],
['sean', '25', 'Art'],
['Rubeena', '18', 'Science'],
['Kareen', '18', 'Science'],
['Rene', '18', 'Geology'],
['Babu', '18', 'Geology'],
['Riggu', '18', 'Robotics'],

]

key = operator.itemgetter(2)
# this step is only required if the list is not sorted by the key
lst.sort(key=key)  

for index, values in itertools.groupby(lst, key):
    print(index)
    for value in values:
        print("    " + " ".join(value))
    print("")
```

**Edit:**

As noted by @tobias_k, it will not work properly if `lst` is not 
sorted by the target column, so you have to make sure it is not the case.

Also replaced `lambda` with `operator.itemgetter` as suggested in comments.

Comment: upvoted, but you could imporve slightly with `operator.itemgetter()` instead of `lambda` for the key

Comment: Only works if the list is sorted by the same key. (Which it is, in this case, but this might also be a coincidence.)

Comment: @taras readability it subjective, but `itemgetter` is marginally faster

Comment: @taras, this code really works in all the situations and produces correct results.

Answer (score 0):

To group your data:

```
In [72]: from collections import defaultdict

In [73]: category_to_list = defaultdict(list)

In [81]: origin_data = [
    ...: ['Jullu', '18', 'Art'],
    ...: ['sean', '25', 'Art'],
    ...: ['Rubeena', '18', 'Science'],
    ...: ['Kareen', '18', 'Science'],
    ...: ['Rene', '18', 'Geology']]

In [82]: category_to_list = defaultdict(list)

In [83]: for i in origin_data:
    ...:     category_to_list[i[2]].append(i)
```

To output as your expect:

```
In [85]: for cate, lst in category_to_list.items():
    ...:     print(cate)
    ...:     for i in lst:
    ...:         print('\t{}'.format(i))
    ...:         
Science
    ['Rubeena', '18', 'Science']
    ['Kareen', '18', 'Science']
Art
    ['Jullu', '18', 'Art']
    ['sean', '25', 'Art']
Geology
    ['Rene', '18', 'Geology']
```

As your sample output without `[ ..]`. so try below way:

```
In [86]: for cate, lst in category_to_list.items():
    ...:     print(cate)
    ...:     for i in lst:
    ...:         print('\t{}'.format(' '.join(i)))
    ...:         
Science
    Rubeena 18 Science
    Kareen 18 Science
Art
    Jullu 18 Art
    sean 25 Art
Geology
    Rene 18 Geology
```

Comment: thnx @Frank for the ideas and your answer i upvote the idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution:

```
v = [
     ['Jullu', '18', 'Art'],
     ['sean', '25', 'Art'],
     ['Rubeena', '18', 'Science'],
     ['Kareen', '18', 'Science'],
     ['Rene', '18', 'Geology'],
     ['Babu', '18', 'Geology'],
     ['Riggu', '18', 'Robotics']
 ]
 v2 =set(map(lambda x: x[2], v))
 for val in v2:
     v3 = list(filter(lambda x: x[2] == val, v))
     print(v3)
```

Explanaition:

```
 v2 =set(map(lambda x: x[2], v))
```

This line extracts all the last different values from the array, mapping every element to its third component and putting everything into a set to exclude duplicates

```
 for val in v2:
     v3 = list(filter(lambda x: x[2] == val, v))
     print(v3)
```

I iterate over the elements of the set, use a filter to extract from the original array the lines where the last element is the actual one and put everything into a list.

I didn't actually display the element as in your example but that should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[['Jullu', '18', 'Art'],
['sean', '25', 'Art'],
['Rubeena', '18', 'Science'],
['Kareen', '18', 'Science'],
['Rene', '18', 'Geology'],
['Babu', '18', 'Geology'],
['Riggu', '18', 'Robotics']]
l=[[x for x in l if x[-1]==i] for i in list(set(list(zip(*l))[-1]))]
for i in l:
   print(i[0][-1])
   print('\n'.join(['\t'+str(x) for x in i]))
```

Output:

```
Robotics
    ['Riggu', '18', 'Robotics']
Science
    ['Rubeena', '18', 'Science']
    ['Kareen', '18', 'Science']
Art
    ['Jullu', '18', 'Art']
    ['sean', '25', 'Art']
Geology
    ['Rene', '18', 'Geology']
    ['Babu', '18', 'Geology']
```

Comment: thnx @U9-Forward for  the answer i appreciate it i upvoted the idea.